# case_when conditional using purrr that reads over column sequence

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, purrr, stringr

I'm trying to classify participants' current status in a course. This is an extension of this post: [purrr pmap to read max column name by column name number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632993/purrr-pmap-to-read-max-column-name-by-column-name-number/56633144?noredirect=1#comment99838608_56633144). My dataset looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
problem <- tibble(name = c("Angela", "Claire", "Justin", "Bob", "Joseph", "Gil"),
                   status_1 = c("Registered", "Withdrawn", "Completed", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered"),
                   status_2 = c("Withdrawn", "Withdrawn", "Registered", "NA", "Withdrawn", "Cancelled"),
                   status_3 = c("NA", "Registered", "Withdrawn", "NA", "Registered", "NA"),
                   status_4 = c("Withdrawn", "Registered", "Withdrawn", "NA", "Registered", "NA"))
```

I want to classify people's current status. If someone has completed the course at any status, their status is "Completed." However, what's tricky is their registered status. Someone is "Registered" IF their final status is registered OR if the later status is "NA". They are NOT registered if a status after their registration is withdrawn or cancelled. So, the final dataset should look this:

```
library(dplyr)
solution <- tibble(name = c("Angela", "Claire", "Justin", "Bob", "Joseph", "Gil"),
                   status_1 = c("Registered", "Withdrawn", "Completed", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered"),
                   status_2 = c("Withdrawn", "Withdrawn", "Registered", "NA", "Withdrawn", "Cancelled"),
                   status_3 = c("NA", "Registered", "Withdrawn", "NA", "Registered", "NA"),
                   status_4 = c("Withdrawn", "Registered", "Withdrawn", "NA", "Registered", "NA"),
                   current = c("Not Taken", "Registered", "Completed", "Registered", "Registered", "Not Taken"))
```

Angela is not taken because she withdrew after her registration. Claire is registered because, despite her past withdrawals, she more recently registered. Justin is completed because he completed the course at any status. Bob is registered because he has not withdrawn or had the course cancelled. Similar to Claire, Joseph has registered more recently than his withdrawal, so he is registered. Finally, Gil is "Not Taken" because his course was canceled, and he doesn't have a more recent registration.

Here's my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
solution %>% 
  mutate(
    test =
      pmap_chr(select(., contains("status")), ~
        case_when(
          any(str_detect(c(...), "(?i)Completed")) ~ "Completed",
          any(str_detect(c(...), "(?i)Exempt")) | any(str_detect(c(...), "(?i)Incomplete")) ~ "Exclude",
          length(c(...) == "Registered") > length(c(...) == "Withdrawn") | length(c(...) == "Registered") > length(c(...) == "Cancelled")  ~ "Registered",
          any(str_detect(c(...), "(?i)No Show")) | any(str_detect(c(...), "(?i)Denied")) | any(str_detect(c(...), "(?i)Cancelled")) | any(str_detect(c(...), "(?i)Waitlist Expired")) || any(str_detect(c(...), "(?i)Withdrawn")) ~ "Not Taken",
          TRUE ~ "NA"
        )
      )
  )
```

I can't figure out how to crack the code with the registration portion. Ideally, I'd like to retain as much of this code as possible because my true dataset has many columns of status.

Thank you!

Comment: @akrun, yes, it is a very similar question to the first link. I cannot figure out how to make it conditional based on the order. In the other questions, the answer revolved around registration being the max or last status. However, some people are registered and have NA as a later status, so they do not get picked up. Others have a cancellation but others have a withdraw after their registration, so they should not be registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem is easier to solve if you first rearrange your data a bit according to ["tidy data" principles](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html), where each time a student's status changed is recorded in a separate row. The rearranged data is in `problem_wrangled`.

Then, the current status can usually be determined by looking only at the most recent status, with the exception of the "Completed" status, for which we check all past statuses.

```r
library(tidyverse)

problem <- tibble(name = c("Angela", "Claire", "Justin", "Bob", "Joseph", "Gil"),
                  status_1 = c("Registered", "Withdrawn", "Completed", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered"),
                  status_2 = c("Withdrawn", "Withdrawn", "Registered", "NA", "Withdrawn", "Cancelled"),
                  status_3 = c("NA", "Registered", "Withdrawn", "NA", "Registered", "NA"),
                  status_4 = c("Withdrawn", "Registered", "Withdrawn", "NA", "Registered", "NA"))

status_wrangled <- problem %>%
  gather(key = "time", value = "status", starts_with("status")) %>%
  mutate(time = as.integer(str_split_fixed(time, "_", 2)[, 2])) %>%
  arrange(name, time) %>%
  filter(status != "NA")

head(status_wrangled)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   name   time  status    
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>     
#> 1 Angela 1     Registered
#> 2 Angela 2     Withdrawn 
#> 3 Angela 4     Withdrawn 
#> 4 Bob    1     Registered
#> 5 Claire 1     Withdrawn 
#> 6 Claire 2     Withdrawn

status_current <- status_wrangled %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(
    current = case_when(
      # Has student completed at any time?
      "Completed" %in% status ~ "Completed",
      # Examine last recorded status
      tail(status, 1) %in% c("Exempt", "Incomplete") ~ "Exclude",
      tail(status, 1) %in% c("Withdrawn", "Cancelled", "No Show", "Denied", "Waitlist Expired") ~ "Not Taken",
      tail(status, 1) == "Registered" ~ "Registered",
      TRUE ~ "Unknown"
    )
  )

print(status_current, n = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   name   current   
#>   <chr>  <chr>     
#> 1 Angela Not Taken 
#> 2 Bob    Registered
#> 3 Claire Registered
#> 4 Gil    Not Taken 
#> 5 Joseph Registered
#> 6 Justin Completed
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT: Regarding your comment about doing approximate matches: I modified the example to allow approximate matches up to a certain edit distance. You probably want to tune this, but allowing up to three edits or so seems reasonable. But be careful, the difference between "Incomplete" and "Completed" is just four edits.

```r
library(tidyverse)

problem <- tibble(name = c("Angela", "Claire", "Justin", "Bob", "Joseph", "Gil"),
                  status_1 = c("Registered", "Withdrawn", "Completed", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered"),
                  status_2 = c("Withdrawn", "Withdrawn", "Registered", "NA", "Withdrawn", "Cancelled"),
                  status_3 = c("NA", "Registered", "Withdrawn", "NA", "Registered", "NA"),
                  status_4 = c("Withdrawnn", "Registered", "Withdrawn", "NA", "Registered", "NA"))

status_wrangled <- problem %>%
  gather(key = "time", value = "status", starts_with("status")) %>%
  mutate(time = as.integer(str_split_fixed(time, "_", 2)[, 2])) %>%
  arrange(name, time) %>%
  filter(status != "NA")

# Find if input vector matches to *any* given pattern below the specified edit distance
any_fuzzy_match <- function(x, patterns, max.distance = 3) {
  matches <- map(paste0("^", patterns, "$"), agrepl, x = x, max.distance = max.distance, fixed = FALSE)
  reduce(matches, `|`)
}

status_current <- status_wrangled %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(
    current = case_when(
      # Has student completed at any time?
      any(any_fuzzy_match(status, "Completed")) ~ "Completed",
      # Examine last recorded status
      any_fuzzy_match(tail(status, 1), c("Exempt", "Incomplete")) ~ "Exclude",
      any_fuzzy_match(tail(status, 1), c("Withdrawn", "Cancelled", "No Show", "Denied", "Waitlist Expired")) ~ "Not Taken",
      any_fuzzy_match(tail(status, 1), "Registered") ~ "Registered",
      TRUE ~ "Unknown"
    )
  )

print(status_current, n = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   name   current   
#>   <chr>  <chr>     
#> 1 Angela Not Taken 
#> 2 Bob    Registered
#> 3 Claire Registered
#> 4 Gil    Not Taken 
#> 5 Joseph Registered
#> 6 Justin Completed
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you! This is great and very parsimonious! One question, is there anyway that it could be modified to do partial matches? For instance, if Angela's status 4 was "Withdrawnn" by mistake, that it could match that withdrawn was still in there?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it works for you. I added a function to do fuzzy matches, I hope that works.

Comment: this function is remarkable--thanks! One question with it, is the max distance saying that it will look up to 3 columns away or 3 characters?

Comment: `max.distance` means that it allows up to so many "edits" (single character deletions, insertions, substitutions) between words (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It does not depend on how far away the columns are from each other. Your example "Withdrawnn" is a single edit (the additional "n") away from "Withdrawn".